# R - rlm - p-values and R-squared after robust regression in R

Tags: r

I am running the following regression in R:

```
require(foreign)
require(MASS)
summary(rr.huber <- rlm(v1 ~ v2, data = all_data_together))
```

for the following variables:

```
> v1
 [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA  83065.81  80315.88 291505.60
 [8] 221513.30 279140.38 298097.06 272173.78 412897.19 387304.74 411286.05
[15] 368148.92 422553.96 387894.51 379685.27 323750.28 348857.20 371270.58
[22] 359926.27 311822.70 368679.20
```

and

```
> v2
 [1] -8.332036 -8.712078 -7.955290 -4.057871 -5.281562 -3.370094 -1.702032
 [8] -2.361179  0.623934  0.400969  1.261043  0.764480  0.360839  0.604281
[15] -2.589645 -0.268268 -0.648042 -1.251618  0.981450 -0.098493 -0.016343
[22]  1.758399  1.897519  2.145591
```

How can I get the p-values and the R-squared for this regression?

EDIT:

```
> new_df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
> dput(new_df)
structure(list(v1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 83065.8078463786, 80315.8839450438, 
291505.602198517, 221513.303866292, 279140.380651832, 298097.0639114, 
272173.784046495, 412897.18764903, 387304.736250378, 411286.048269894, 
368148.919445238, 422553.963363549, 387894.509272978, 379685.266347887, 
323750.28443457, 348857.195576222, 371270.579837624, 359926.267077774, 
311822.695796726, 368679.198734135), v2 = c(-8.332036, -8.712078, 
-7.95529, -4.057871, -5.281562, -3.370094, -1.702032, -2.361179, 
0.623934, 0.400969, 1.261043, 0.76448, 0.360839, 0.604281, -2.589645, 
-0.268268, -0.648042, -1.251618, 0.98145, -0.098493, -0.016343, 
1.758399, 1.897519, 2.145591)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: Could you please place your variables in a data frame and post its `dput`? Or just `dput(all_together_data)`

Comment: You can use the solution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205614/p-values-and-significance-in-rlm-mass-package-r)

Comment: Hello @NelsonGon, I have edited my post and pasted the output of dput.

Comment: Was the above solution less convincing?

Comment: I am trying to run the code from the link you pasted but I am getting the following error: `> library(sfsmisc)

Attaching package: ‘sfsmisc’

The following object is masked from ‘package:Hmisc’:

    errbar` . maybe you can post a comment adapted to my variables etc below?

Comment: I'm on phone now. Issues with my computer. Will do as soon as I fix my PC. However that is not an error, just information that the same function exists in a different package.

Comment: I was able to run it successfully by simply running: `f.robftest(rr.huber)`.

Comment: I run it and I get `> f.robftest(rsl)

 robust F-test (as if non-random weights)

data:  from rlm(formula = v1 ~ v2, data = all_data_together)
F = 10.015, p-value = 0.005363
alternative hypothesis: true v2 is not equal to 0`. Is that the p-value of the coefficient? And is there a way to show the R-squared and Adjusted R-squared as well?